# Amazon DynamoDB :1 validation error detected: Value '0' at 'segment' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to -1

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

This is my query :

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'UserGroup',

    // optional expression to filter results
    FilterExpression: '#groupId = :val',

    // optional - list of attributes to return (default is to return all)
    //ProjectionExpression: 'STRING_VALUE',

    // optional - if used by relevant expressions
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#groupId': 'groupId',
        // ... more expression attribute names ...
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':val':{'S':'f8803eb0-8210-11e5-9d6b-bb8d7a911aab'},
        // ... more expression attribute values ...
    },

    Limit: 1, // optional (limit the number of items to evaluate)
    Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES', // optional (ALL_ATTRIBUTES | COUNT)
    Segment: 0, // optional (for parallel scan)
    TotalSegments: 0, // optional (for parallel scan)
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | TOTAL | INDEXES)
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) print(err); // an error occurred
    else print(data); // successful response});
}
```

I am trying to scan the data from the Dynamo Db But it throws the Error.during fetching the data,Since scan query result all the data from the database but i want to filter the result return b the query.
Can any body give the query to fetch the filter scan result in dynamoDb usin 
node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Segment` value isn't validating correctly.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_RequestParameters):

> Segment
>   For a parallel Scan request, Segment identifies an individual segment to be scanned by an application worker.
>
> Segment IDs are zero-based, so the first segment is always 0. For example, if you want to use four application threads to scan a table or an index, then the first thread specifies a Segment value of 0, the second thread specifies 1, and so on.
>
> The value of LastEvaluatedKey returned from a parallel Scan request must be used as ExclusiveStartKey with the same segment ID in a subsequent Scan operation.
>
> **The value for Segment must be greater than or equal to 0, and less than the value provided for TotalSegments.**
>
> If you provide Segment, you must also provide TotalSegments.

Try either getting rid of the segment specification or making `TotalSegments` equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `Segment` and `TotalSegments` are incorrect.

Documentation from [`Segment`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Segment), emphasis mine:

> **Segment IDs are zero-based, so the first segment is always 0**. For example, if you want to use four application threads to scan a table or an index, then the first thread specifies a `Segment` value of 0, the second thread specifies 1, and so on.
>
> The value of `LastEvaluatedKey` returned from a parallel `Scan` request must be used as `ExclusiveStartKey` with the same segment ID in a subsequent `Scan` operation.
>
> **The value for `Segment` must be greater than or equal to 0, and less than the value provided for `TotalSegments`.**
>
> **If you provide `Segment`, you must also provide `TotalSegments`.**
>
> Type: Number
>
> Valid range: Minimum value of 0. Maximum value of 999999.
>
> Required: No

Documentation from [`TotalSegments`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-TotalSegments), emphasis mine:

> **The value for `TotalSegments` must be greater than or equal to 1**, and less than or equal to 1000000. If you specify a `TotalSegments` value of 1, the `Scan` operation will be sequential rather than parallel.
>
> If you specify `TotalSegments`, you must also specify `Segment`.
>
> Type: Number
>
> Valid range: **Minimum value of 1**. Maximum value of 1000000.

Either update your parameters to fit the API requirements, or get rid of both of them so that it is no longer a parallel scan.